# Entity Framework Code First Migrations Guid NewId Instead Of NewSequentialId

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

We're using EF6 with code first migrations pointing to an Azure SQL.  We've started into using some Guid for both primary keys as well as alongside int primary keys.
Primary Key:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

Alongside int PK:

```
[Index, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid PolymorphicId { get; set; }
```

When I generate the migration, I get as follows (respectively):

```
Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
PolymorphicId = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
```

**Expectation**: SQL generated to have default values of newsequentialid

**Actually Happening**:

```
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT newid(),
[PolymorphicId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT newid(),
```

How do I make my EF migrations generate with newsequentialid instead of newid? Everything I've looked up online says that they should be generating with newsequentialid.

Comment: Why are you using GUID as type and not int?

Comment: Depends on the situation. Sometimes we need Guids, sometimes we need ints. I'm well aware of the debate of int vs Guid for keys; is that relevant to the issue?

Answer (score 2):

When targeting Azure, SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator will default to "newid()". When targeting on-premesis Sql Server 2005 or later, it will default to "newsequentialid()".
Source: [GitHub SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.cs)

Optional fix: Create a custom SqlGenerator, inheriting SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator, override GuidColumnDefault

Optional fix: As posted by JFM, modify the generated migration file, setting the defaultValueSql

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the sql used by the sql server column key generation in your migration script, I beleive it should look somethnig similar to this:

```
Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true, defaultValueSql: "newsequentialid()")
```

Comment: I'll probably end up doing that, however I would like to know how to do it 'by default', and possibly why it's not doing it by default to begin with when everything I'm reading says it should be.

Comment: Think I found an answer...why it's this way, I don't know...in the SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator, it states that Guids will generate with newsequentialid() for local SQL servers and newid() for Azure. I am pointing to Azure.  Any clue why this is?